# Where can i find the maven dependencies for Webshpere eXtreme Scale?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-extreme-scale

I have been googling for some days now about this. I am trying to develop a spring boot application (which is going to be deployed into a Websphere Liberty Profile Server), and is going to connect to Websphere Extreme scale for caching. I went through several documentations and guides, but none of them provide an actual source of where to find the dependencies for connecting to wxs from a maven built application.

I had assumed that the required jars should have been bundled along with the wxs liberty feature installation. But I could not find it in the lib directory of the server either.

I believe I am looking for 
file=objectgrid.jar,groupId=com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid,artifactId=objectgrid,version=8.6.0.2

Any links towards a sample java maven application that connects to wxs will also be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required jars are indeed included in the WXS Liberty installation. However the namings were'nt `objectgrid` or `ogclient` as stated in different docs.

The only required client jar for developing a wxs client application is sized at 15MB, named `com.ibm.ws.xs.client_1.1` and in the directory [WASDir]/dev/ibm-api.

You can add this jar to your applications build path and develop wxs client applications.

If you are using maven, (I was), you could install the above jar in your local maven repository with a `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=? -DgroupId=? -DartifactId=? -Dversion=? -Dpackaging=jar` and use the installed dependency in your project.

Note that, these are only for development purposes.(as are all the Liberty Features)